# Routing of Api Controllers Design

Tags: asp.net, rest, api, design-patterns

I'm creating a dotnet core web api and have defined my api spec.
For now i have users which can have assignments linked to eachother.

For creating an user i'm using this route:

```
POST /users
{
  "name": "User name"
}
```

This is all done within a `Userscontroller`

For creating an assignment and hook it up to an user i thought of this url:
`/users/{userId}/assignments` and adding a `GET/POST/PATCH/DELETE` method.

My question: would one split it in multiple controllers (userscontroller and assignmentcontroller) or one controller (userscontroller) and generate routes from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a personal preference, and also depends on how big `UsersController` is.

If I have too many codes in `UsersController`, I might consider creating `AssignmentController`. It is about following *Single Responsibility Principle*.

On the other hand, if everything inside `UsersController` is related to user, I'll just keep it there. *You can look at [this](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/blob/develop/src/Presentation/Nop.Web/Administration/Controllers/CustomerController.cs) controller as sample.*

Comment: I've decided to split the controllers to different controllers to respect the single responsibility principle